# Acceleration due to gravity?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites

I was looking into orbitals and found something I haven't been able to understand.

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-01a/hunter/satelliteOrbits.html

There is a part on the page which states the following:
$$\vec a = \frac{G(M+m)\vec{r}}{r^3}\approx GM\vec{r} / r^3$$ since $m << M$

I'm not sure why this is the case and why we do not use $\vec a = \vec F/m$ here.  The cubed radius is really throwing me off. Can anyone further explain this or point me to a reference with a proof? Thanks

Comment: Very subtle: The $r$ in the numerator is written in boldface, $\textbf{r}$, which means that it's a vector, which has magnitude $r$ and a particular direction. To get a vector of length $1$ but with the same direction, just divide by $r$ again. That gives you the $r^3$ in the denominator.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please add yor level of knowlegde about Kepler's laws.

Comment: Greetings Tyrick. Have a look at [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1) to learn how to typeset equations on the SE sites.

Comment: Thanks, Lagerbaer.  I simply didn't see the vector r, in the numerator.  ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$${\bf F} = \mu {\bf a}$$
where $\mu = M m/(M+m)$ is the [reduced mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass). 
Thus, 
$$\frac{G M m}{r^3}{\bf r} = \frac{M m}{M+m}{\bf a}$$
or 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf a} &=& \frac{G(M+m)}{r^3}{\bf r} \\
&=& \frac{G M}{r^3}{\bf r}\left(1+\frac{m}{M}\right) \\
&\simeq& \frac{G M}{r^3}{\bf r}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Notice that $m/M \simeq 10^{-19}$.
The error accrued by neglecting this term is very small indeed.

As mentioned by @Lagerbaer, the ratio you find troubling involves the vector ${\bf r}$ divided by $r^3$.
This can be written as 
$$\frac{{\bf r}}{r^3} = \frac{\hat r}{r^2}$$
where $\hat r$ is the unit vector in the ${\bf r}$ direction. 
The magnitude of the gravitational force will be the familiar one since 
$|{\bf r}/r^3| = 1/r^2$.